# Deleting address/queue without restarting broker by modifing broker.xml

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.7.0

Using the configuration reload functionality addresses and queues can be seen in console by editing `broker.xml` without restarting the ActiveMQ Artemis process. However, when removing them from `broker.xml` messages are still getting sent to and receive from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enforcing the deletion of addresses and queues from `broker.xml` at runtime (via configuration reload) is not enforced by default as there is a risk inadvertent data loss. If you want to force addresses and queues to be deleted upon removal from `broker.xml` at runtime you need to set the `<config-delete-addresses>` & `<config-delete-queues>` address settings to `FORCE`. See [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html) for more details.

Comment: Where do these nodes go int the configuration please? Let us know what the parent XML node is. The documentation sure doesn't. Heck, it won't even tell if if it is a node or attribute.

Comment: The [cited documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html) clearly states, "Deletion of Address's and Queue's, not auto created is controlled by **Address Settings**." You can find more details about address settings in the [Address Model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings) chapter of the documentation. Also, the default `broker.xml` has an `address-settings` section defined so adding these elements should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Ok...Well, first off, there is no node called "Address Settings" but there is a <address-settings> node. `<address-settings><config-delete-addresses>FORCE...` does not  parse and throws exceptions on start. It seems to actually go under <address-setting> which is under <address-settings>, but I have no idea why you'd specify to delete all unused addresses under a particular address...So, it isn't clear at all.

Comment: As I noted previously, the [address model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#configuring-addresses-and-queues-via-address-settings) chapter of the documentation demonstrates how to set address settings. I'm not sure how much clearer that could be. Perhaps looking at one of the examples in the `examples` directory would help. Many of them use address settings.

Comment: Users have all kinds of different use-cases which is why the configuration is flexible. Just because you have "no idea why you'd specify to delete all unused addresses under a particular address" doesn't mean it's invalid. Keep in mind that `config-delete-addresses` applies to the address itself and not just the queues bound to that address.